# Swift combine handling HTTP status code errors

Tags: swift, combine

I was reading this article: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4161005-mvvm-with-combine-tutorial-for-ios on Ray Wenderlich about how to use combine. They have an example where it fetches data from an API but it doesn't handle HTTP status codes. I wanted to add it but so far I'm not able to do so.

According to this answer you could add a `tryMap` but then XCode starts showing errors like: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`.

Below the code:

```swift
extension WeatherFetcher: WeatherFetchable {
  func weeklyWeatherForecast(
    forCity city: String
  ) -> AnyPublisher<WeeklyForecastResponse, WeatherError> {
    return forecast(with: makeWeeklyForecastComponents(withCity: city))
  }

  private func forecast<T>(
    with components: URLComponents
  ) -> AnyPublisher<T, WeatherError> where T: Decodable {
    guard let url = components.url else {
      let error = WeatherError.network(description: "Couldn't create URL")
      return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: url))
      .mapError { error in
        .network(description: error.localizedDescription)
    }
    .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { pair in
      decode(pair.data)
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

And I was trying to add

```swift
.tryMap { data, response in
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
            switch (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode {
            case (400...499):
                throw ServiceErrors.internalError((response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
            default:
                throw ServiceErrors.serverError((response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
            }
    }
    return data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply replace the `flatMap` block with `tryMap`. And instead of returning data from `tryMap`, it should be decoded T. So `return data` line should be `return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)`

```
private func forecast<T>(with components: URLComponents) -> AnyPublisher<T, WeatherError> where T: Decodable {
guard let url = components.url else {
    let error = WeatherError.network(description: "Couldn't create URL")
    return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: url))
    .tryMap { data, response in
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                switch (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode {
                case (400...499):
            throw ServiceErrors.internalError((response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
                default:
                    throw ServiceErrors.serverError((response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
                }
        }
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
.mapError { error in
    WeatherError() // some kind of error
}
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

}